# binary operator expected using ! -z?

Tags: bash, scripts

I tried searching for similar problems, but can't find one that makes sense for my code.  I just started about 2 weeks ago, so that may just be an inability to understand migrating answers for one case to another.

I have a code to look up all directories in a file and search each file for a word input, then eventually put any of the files with non-blank outputs into a file.

I've been using the grep line:

```
g=$(grep -ni "$word" $myfile)

if [ ! -z $g ]; then

echo "the file inside is: $myfile"

fi
```

I can put the complete code up, but this is the error:

```
/home/anthony/myscripts/wordturbo3.sh: line 22: [: 17:chemistry: binary operator expected
```

(for the word=chemistry, program=wordturbo3.sh)

This error only populates after I use the grep command with the `! -z` qualifiers.  The answer key I have writes it a little differently: it uses an if-else command (`if -z, else`) instead of (`! -z`) for just an if portion (no else).  This seems to require that my if condition, `-z`, have an output in order to function (such as echo "this file is empty").

However, I am looking through many more files than the example and would like to not have to echo "this file is empty" hundreds of times just so that I can accomplish the "else" portion of the command.  Therefore, I was simply trying to circumvent this need by using (`! -z`) for just the if portion.

It accomplishes what I want, but it first spits out 17 or so lines of the "binary operator expected."

Is there a simple workaround to this?

Thank you in advance for the advice.

edit: oh, and I found a suggestion online to use `-n` instead of `-z` for indicate "contains information" rather than "empty" but this didn't seem to work.  The program didn't work when I replaced (`! -z`) with (`-n`).

Answer (score 3):

Probably the issue is that your `grep` returns multiple matches, and the unquoted `$g` inside `[ ! -z $g ]` is undergoing word splitting.

Ex. given

```
$ cat myfile
foo
bar
Foo
Bar
```

then

```
$ g=$(grep -ni foo myfile)
$ echo $g
1:foo 3:Foo
```

so

```
$ [ ! -z $g ]
bash: [: 1:foo: binary operator expected
```

The error message is because `-z` is a *unary operator* i.e. it expects a single argument; since you have given two arguments to `[` ... `]` it expects you to have used a binary operator (like `-eq`).

If you quote the variable expansion  i.e. `"$g"`, all the matches returned by `grep` will be treated as a single argument, so the `-z` unary test will work:

```
$ [ ! -z "$g" ] && echo "non empty"
non empty
```

**However** you don't need any of this - instead, just check the *exit status* of grep itself:

```
$ if grep -qi foo myfile; then echo "foo is in myfile"; fi
foo is in myfile
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It was the quoted "$g" that caused the error.  I'm trying to understand your final line- what is -q?  Is that "not empty"?

Comment: @izardle the `-q` tells grep to "be quiet" - it doesn't output anything, but its exit status will be TRUE (zero) if a match was found and FALSE (non zero) otherwise. It's also more efficient as it will exit on the first match. See `man grep`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to change:

```
if [ ! -z $g ]; then
```

to

```
if [ ! -z "$g" ]; then
```

However, I don't quite understand why yet.  I'll keep looking on the web, but if anyone has any thoughts, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you!